# Tkinter, make a window when certain conditions are met?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to run a Tkinter window if the user enters a specific number, but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
#Import Tkinter module
from tkinter import *

ans = int (input('What is 100 x 10? '))
if ans == int ('1000'):

        #Create a window and set Geometry
        pyr = Tk()
        pyr.geometry('300x300')

        #Title window
        pyr.title("Right")

        #Set background color using hex code
        pyr.configure(background = "#32cd32")

        #Create Labels
        lbl = Label(pyr, text="Correct!", bg="#32cd32")

        # Packing
        lbl.grid(column=2, row=1)


        #Draw window and start application
        pyr.mainloop

else:
        #Create a window and set Geometry
        pyw = Tk()
        pyw.geometry('300x300')

        #Title window
        pyw.title("Wrong")

        #Set background color using hex code
        pyw.configure(background = "#ff0000")

        #Create Labels
        lbl1 = Label(pyw, text="Nope!", bg="#32cd32")

        # Packing
        lbl1.grid(column=2, row=1)

        #Draw window and start application
        pyw.mainloop()
```

What happens is I enter 1000 or a different number and nothing happens. It just sits there, doesn't even print a ">>>" to show it's done. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I think you have a typo. Should `pyf.geometry('300x300')` be `pyr.geometry('300x300')` ?

Comment: 1) pyr.mainloop() 2) Carefully assign parent containers to widgets (pyf, pyr, pyw)

Comment: yeah it should. I was reusing an old code for parts, forgot to change it. Didn't make a diff though

Comment: `ans == int ('1000')` You are aware that you can just check `ans == 1000`?

Comment: I know, doesn't change the outcome thoguh

Comment: I take it back, taking away the `int (' ')` made it come back with the >>> thing

Comment: Went through and took out all "pyf"s and replaced appropriately. Only came back with >>>; window did not open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two main problems with your code are basically two typos:

1. You forgot to *call* the `mainloop` function in the "correct" case (add `()`)
2. You are using `pyf` instead of `pyr` and `pyw` in some places

I'd also suggest moving the window-opening stuff into a method to reduce code duplication and using `isdigit` to check whether the input is a number before trying to cast to `int`.

```
def open_window(title, message, color):
    pyr = Tk()
    pyr.geometry('300x300')
    pyr.title(title)
    pyr.configure(background = color)
    lbl = Label(pyr, text=message, bg=color)
    lbl.grid(column=2, row=1)
    pyr.mainloop()

ans = input('What is 100 x 10? ')
if ans.isdigit() and int(ans) == 1000:
    open_window("Right", "Correct", "#32cd32")
else:
    open_window("Wrong", "Nope", "#ff0000")
```

Comment: Thanks! This works when the answer is wrong. When it's right it doesn't do anything, doesn't even print >>>

Comment: nevermind, the tkinter window was behind the Python IDLE window haha sorry about that. Thanks a lot man!